# how to call the viewPager adapter from another fragmentClass

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need to implement a fragment replacement in the ViewPager.

After some search, I found this adapter (that seems to work good):

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{

private final AppCompatActivity mActivity;
private final TabLayout tabLayout;
private final ViewPager mPager;
private List<TabInfo> mTabs = new LinkedList<TabInfo>();
private int TOTAL_TABS;

private Map<Integer, Stack<TabInfo>> history = new HashMap<Integer, Stack<TabInfo>>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(AppCompatActivity activity, ViewPager pager, TabLayout tabLayout)
{
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mPager = pager;
    this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
}

public void addTab(final Class fragmentClass, final Bundle args)
{
    final TabInfo tabInfo = new TabInfo(fragmentClass, args);
    tabLayout.newTab();
    tabLayout.setTag(tabInfo);

    mTabs.add(tabInfo);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position)
{
    final TabInfo tabInfo = mTabs.get(position);
    return Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, tabInfo.fragmentClass.getName(), tabInfo.args);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(final Object object) {

    int position = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
    int pos = POSITION_NONE;

    if (history.get(position).isEmpty()) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    for (Stack<TabInfo> stack : history.values()) {
        TabInfo c = stack.peek();
        if (c.fragmentClass.getName().equals(object.getClass().getName())) {
            pos = POSITION_UNCHANGED;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{

}

public void onTabSelected(final FragmentTransaction ft) {
    TabInfo tabInfo = (TabInfo) tabLayout.getTag();
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
        if (mTabs.get(i).equals(tabInfo)) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    }
}

public void onTabUnselected(FragmentTransaction ft) {
}


public void onTabReselected(FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

public void replace(final int position, final Class fragmentClass, final Bundle args)
{
    mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();
    updateTabs(new TabInfo(fragmentClass, args), position);
    history.get(position).push(new TabInfo(mTabs.get(position).fragmentClass, mTabs.get(position).args));

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void updateTabs(final TabInfo tabInfo, final int position)
{
    mTabs.remove(position);
    mTabs.add(position, tabInfo);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setTag(tabInfo);
}

public void createHistory()
{
    int position = 0;
    TOTAL_TABS = mTabs.size();
    for (TabInfo mTab : mTabs)
    {
        if (history.get(position) == null)
        {
            history.put(position, new Stack<TabInfo>());
        }
        history.get(position).push(new TabInfo(mTab.fragmentClass, mTab.args));
        position++;
    }
}


public void back()
{
    int position = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
    if (!historyIsEmpty(position))
    {
        if (isLastItemInHistory(position))
        {
            mActivity.finish();
        }
        final TabInfo currentTabInfo = getPrevious(position);
        mTabs.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TABS; i++)
        {
            if (i == position)
            {
              mTabs.add(new TabInfo(currentTabInfo.fragmentClass, currentTabInfo.args));
            }
            else
            {
              TabInfo otherTabInfo = history.get(i).peek();
              mTabs.add(new TabInfo(otherTabInfo.fragmentClass, otherTabInfo.args));
            }
        }
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private boolean historyIsEmpty(final int position)
{
    return history == null || history.isEmpty() || history.get(position).isEmpty();
}

private boolean isLastItemInHistory(final int position)
{
    return history.get(position).size() == 1;
}

private TabInfo getPrevious(final int position)
{
    TabInfo currentTabInfo = history.get(position).pop();
    if (!history.get(position).isEmpty()) {
        currentTabInfo = history.get(position).peek();
    }
    return currentTabInfo;
}


private static class TabInfo
{
 public Class fragmentClass;
 public Bundle args;

 public TabInfo(Class fragmentClass, Bundle args)
 {
        this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
        this.args = args;
 }

    public boolean equals(final Object o)
    {
        return this.fragmentClass.getName().equals(o.getClass().getName());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return fragmentClass.getName() != null ? fragmentClass.getName().hashCode() : 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "TabInfo{" +
                "fragmentClass=" + fragmentClass +
                '}';
    }
}
}
```

and I need to call methods `replace()` and `back()` in this adapter.

This is how I call this adapter from `WindFragment` in `setupViewPager()` method:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, TabLayout tabLayout)
 {
     adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter((AppCompatActivity)getActivity(),viewPager,tabLayout);

     adapter.addTab(THGSFragment.class,null);
     adapter.addTab(FlightPerformanceFragment.class,null);
     adapter.addTab(AviationConverterFragment.class,null);
     adapter.addTab(SpeedFragment.class,null);

     adapter.createHistory();

     viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
     tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(getString(R.string.thgs));
     tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(getString(R.string.tcgs));
     tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText(getString(R.string.wv));
     tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setText(getString(R.string.thtas));

 }
```

now I'm in this class:

```
public class THGSFragment extends Fragment
{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_thg, container, false);

    ImageView button= (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calcEAS);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

and in the `onClick()` method I need to call the method `replace()` from the adapter, but I don't know how.

So, I need to use an interface (that I'm not good to use) ?

Thank you

Comment: I'd be tempted to use an event bus for this.

Comment: @Jahnold not interface?

Comment: You could definitely do it with an interface...it's just a preference thing.  An event bus would mean slightly less boilerplate and is more loosely coupled.